# Why is my virtual method being skipped over in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, factory, factory-pattern, roguelike

Long story short: The program I'm working on is a rogue like - even though that isn't really needed for this question.

Here's the hierarchy tree for my classes related to this question:

```
                                     Entity
                        Item                     Creature
                  Weapon     Armor
```

I have several virtual functions declared in Entity, which are also virtual in the classes derived from it.

I'm not sure how to word my question, but I'll explain the problem and post the code below. I have a **factory** type class, called **ItemFactory,** that opens an xml file and uses a simple parser that I made - and creates Item objects and sets their values. It has a method that returns an **Item** pointer. In my main file, I declare/define an **ItemFactory** object. When an **Item** needs to be dropped in the game, I use a pointer, that is of type, **Item**,
and call the method to randomly choose an **Item** to point to. All of this works perfectly..

Here's the problem. **Entity** has a virtual method called **dumpObject()** which prints the state of the variables it has. **dumpObject()** is also virtual in **Item**. When it's called from an **Item**, the method first calls **Entity's** dump with this:

```
                 Entity::dumpObject();
```

Then it dumps it's own variables.. I do the same for **Weapon** and **Armor** except using this:

```
                 Item::dumpObject();
```

### My Question:

Since the **ItemFactory** holds both - **Weapons** and **Armor**, and the pointer in the main program points to an **Item**, shouldn't calling ***"itemPointer->dumpObject();"*** dump the values for Weapon/Armor (depending which it is pointing to..) which would also dump the values in **Item** which would also dump the values in **Entity**?

When I run the code, the only part that gets dumped is the part in Item and Entity.

Let me know if I need to provide more detail. Any suggestions? Thanks!

### Here's the Code Snippets

I have the headers included, just tried to minimize the amount of code that I'm posting

---

**Item.cpp**

```
void Item::dumpObject(){
    cout << "Item:" << endl;
    dumpObjectData();
}

void Item::dumpObjectData(){
    Entity::dumpObjectData();
    cout << "        [Weight] " << getWeight() << endl;
    cout << "         [Value] " << getValue() << endl;
    cout << "      [Quantity] " << getQuantity() << endl;
    cout << "   [Enchantment] " << getEnchantment() << endl;
}
```

---

**Entity.cpp**

```
void Entity::dumpObject(){
    cout << "Entity:" << endl;
    dumpObjectData();
}

void Entity::dumpObjectData(){
    XMLSerializable::dumpObjectData(); //XMLSerialization handles parsing

    cout << "          [Name] " << getName() << endl;
    cout << "   [DisplayChar] " << getDisplayChar() << endl;
    cout << "    [Properties] " << endl;

    for( auto it = m_vProperties.begin(); it != m_vProperties.end();it++ ){
            cout << "       - " << (*it) << endl;
    }
}
```

---

**Weapon.cpp**

```
void Weapon::dumpObject(){
    cout << "Weapon:" << endl;
    dumpObjectData();
}

void Weapon::dumpObjectData(){
    Item::dumpObjectData();

    cout << "        [Damage] " << getDamage() << endl;
    cout << "         [Range] " << getRange() << endl;
    cout << "      [Accuracy] " << getAccuracy() << endl;
    cout << "      [AmmoType] " << getAmmoType() << endl;
    cout << "          [Type] " << getType() << endl;
}
```

---

**Armor.cpp**

```
void Armor::dumpObject(){
    cout << "Armor:" << endl;
    dumpObjectData();
}

void Armor::dumpObjectData(){
    cout << "calls to dump item data"<<endl;
    Item::dumpObjectData();
    cout << "calls to dump armor"<<endl;
    cout << "          [Type] " << getType() << endl;
    cout << "          [Slot] " << getSlot() << endl;
    cout << "    [ArmorValue] " << getArmorValue() << endl;

}
```

---

**Main**

```
    ItemFactory myItems = ItemFactory::instance();
    Item * pItem1 = myItems.generateItem();
    pItem1->dumpObject();
```

---

---

---

### Headers

**Entity.h**

```
#include "XMLSerializable.h"
#include <vector>

class Entity : public XMLSerializable {

public:
    Entity(void);
    virtual ~Entity(void);

    virtual void dumpObject();
    virtual void dumpObjectData();

};
```

---

**Item.h**

```
#include "Entity.h"

class Item : public Entity{

public:
    Item(void);
    virtual ~Item(void);

    virtual void dumpObject();
    virtual void dumpObjectData();
```

};

---

**Weapon.h**

```
#include "Item.h"

class Weapon : public Item {
public:
    Weapon(void);
    virtual ~Weapon(void);

    virtual void dumpObject();
    virtual void dumpObjectData();
   
};
```

---

**Armor.h**

```
#include "Item.h"

class Armor : public Item {
public:
    Armor(void);
    virtual ~Armor(void);

    virtual void dumpObject();
    virtual void dumpObjectData();

};
```

---

**ItemFactory.cpp**

```
ItemFactory & ItemFactory::instance(){
    static ItemFactory myObj;
    return myObj;
}

ItemFactory::ItemFactory(){
    m_mtRandom.seed( time(NULL) );
    fstream xmlFile;
    xmlFile.open("items.xml");
    vector<XMLSerializable*> pObjects;
    parseXML(xmlFile, pObjects);

    XMLSerializable * pObject;

    for(auto it = pObjects.begin(); it != pObjects.end(); it++){
            pObject = (*it);
            Item * pItem = dynamic_cast<Item*>(pObject);
            if (pItem != NULL){
                    m_vItems.push_back(pItem);
            }
    }
}


ItemFactory::~ItemFactory(){

}


Item * ItemFactory::generateItem() {
    vector<Item*> tempItems;

    for(auto it = m_vItems.begin(); it != m_vItems.end(); it++){
            tempItems.push_back((*it));
    }

    int randomItem = (m_mtRandom() % (m_vItems.size() - 1));


    Item * pItem = tempItems.at(randomItem);

    Item * pReturnValue = new Item(*pItem);

    return pReturnValue;
}
```

Now that I just did all that work, I don't think any of the code except maybe Main was necessary.. Lol I'm guessing my logic for the pointer in Main is wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the class declarations?

Comment: Can post your definition of myItems.generateItem()? Like pitem1 points to an item

Comment: Are these the actual headers from your code, or have you tidied them up? Any `const` removed from methods for example?

Comment: @JiuDong yeah, just added it.

Comment: @Keith the only things I removed were the other methods and variables that weren't used

Comment: Is there some reason you are making copies of items? `Item * pReturnValue = new Item(*pItem);` (And, this creates an `Item`, which is the wrong class.)

Comment: Stylistic comment: "dump" methods shouldn't normally mutate state - mark them as "const".

Comment: It is either not making a virtual call or the vtable that the object is pointing to contains functions corresponding to only Item. May be due to mismatching definitions of the classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well here's your problem:

```
Item * pReturnValue = new Item(*pItem);
```

This is giving you a shallow copy so that you do not get an `Armor` or `Weapon`.

If you need to do a copy given only a base class instance, define a `clone` method in the base class.

It looks like you are trying to use the `prototype` pattern, so you do want to create new instances?

```
class Entity : public XMLSerializable {

public:
    Entity(void);
    virtual ~Entity(void);

    virtual Entity* clone() const { return new Entity(*this);}

    virtual void dumpObject();
    virtual void dumpObjectData();
```

};

```
class Armor : public Item {
public:
    Armor(void);
    virtual ~Armor(void);
    virtual Armor* clone() const { return new Armor (*this);}
    virtual void dumpObject();
    virtual void dumpObjectData();

};
```

Note the use of covariant return values for `clone()`. I.e. The return values do differ but as the method signature matches and the return values are derived from one another, the call is virtual.

You then can write:

```
Item * pReturnValue = pItem->clone();
```

See: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) for background on the Prototype pattern.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with how copy constructors work and when to use them really. I know that they usually come back to haunt me though. I'm not sure what you mean about that last part, sorry. I'm not good with the technical terms

Comment: Key question - do you want `generate` to create a new object, or a handle to an existing object?

Comment: If you want to clone an item whose type you do not know, you have to use the correct code for the type of that object. The natural way to do that is with a virtual function. However, just doing `Item(*foo)` will *always* construct an `Item`, even if `*foo` is of some other type derived from `Item`.

Comment: @Justin If you want to copy objects, you do need to correctly implement the copy constructor - no way around that.

Comment: It looks like your fix is just to change `Item * pItem = tempItems.at(randomItem); Item * pReturnValue = new Item(*pItem);    return pReturnValue;` to `return tempItems.at(randomItem);`. There seems to be no reason to make a copy.

Comment: Ok, I think I somewhat understand that. Won't I have to change a lot of code around to make it pure virtual/abstract? The player class has a member variable that is a pointer to an Item, so after the ItemFactory is created, won't it be like handling an existing object since it changes what Item is being pointed to?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that kind of worked, thanks! It looks like it's dumping Armor correctly and the Weapons dump correctly, but is missing the last 2 values. Which is probably a mess up somewhere else that I haven't been able to look for yet. Thanks though!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It looks like the Weapon values are correct for the values dumped by Item and Entity, but the values dumped by Weapon's method are the defaults.